# Linking error of a header file in xcode , when made a static libary

Tags: objective-c, categories

What I was doing is as follows..
1) First I used the OAConsumer library and Base64 library in my project and I made a cocoa touch static library of it along with my own classes..
2)When I use this library in my project , 
it is not able to link the NSData + BAse64.m file

I get the following error and it crashes ..

```
-[NSConcreteData base64EncodedString] : Unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x158250
```

This question is similar to the following question .. 
[Categories in Objective-C aren't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137988/categories-in-objective-c-arent-working)

I tried the solutions in it ... but didn't work ...

Comment: What is your question? `NSData` does not have a `-base64EncodedString:` method, so it makes sense that you'd get an Unrecognized selector exception.

Comment: i have edited the question ...i using Base64 library also

Comment: You should run your app in the debugger and set it to break on Objective-C exceptions (on throw). When it stops, check to see what object is getting sent the `base64EncodedString` method. That should point you to where and possibly what the problem is.

Comment: the program crashed hard...and its unable to recover ..

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and try again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163981/how-to-add-a-breakpoint-to-objc-exception-throw