# Categories in Objective C not working

Tags: ios, objective-c-category, nsset, coreparse

I have a similar problem to the link below.

[Categories in Objective-C aren't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137988/categories-in-objective-c-arent-working)

I'm a newbie to Objective C, so please excuse the ignorance. I need to support themes in my project, and I found this interesting solution (https://github.com/tombenner/nui) that I am trying to integrate into my solution. I have integrated the project as explained in the installation instructions on the nui page. This software is dependent on CoreParse which needs to be added as a sub-project to you app. I have done this.

The folder structure is as follows:

```
--CODE
   --CoreParse
   --MyApp
       -ExternalProjects
```

I dragged the Coreparse project file into the ExternalProject Subfolder in my project.

When I run the project, I kept getting messages like "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81b42e0" which I fixed by simply combining ALL the category code into the parent class.

Now I am encountering the same error again, only this time it is in a category extension of the NSSet class in the Apple libraries, so my combining workaround will not suffice.

The error I get is:

2014-03-26 11:16:16.358 MomApp[1409:c07] -[__NSSetM cp_map:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81b0210

When I do a "po" on my error, I get the following:

`po 0x81b0210
$0 = 139762688 {(
    (null) ::= •
)}`

Edit:
The code calling this comes from a packege I downloaded on github (CoreParse)

```
    while ([processingQueue count] > 0)
{
    NSSet *kernel = [processingQueue objectAtIndex:0];
    NSSet *itemSet = [self lr0Closure:kernel];
    //The next line causes the error
    NSSet *validNexts = [itemSet cp_map:^ id (CPItem *item) {return [item nextSymbol];}];

    for (CPGrammarSymbol *s in validNexts)
    {
        NSSet *g = [self lr0GotoKernelWithItems:itemSet symbol:s];
        if (![c containsObject:g])
        {
            [processingQueue addObject:g];
            [c addObject:g];
        }
    }

    [processingQueue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
```

The .h and .m files where this extension resides are shown below:
.h File

```
//
//  NSSetFunctional.h
//  CoreParse
//
//  Created by Tom Davie on 06/03/2011.
//  Copyright 2011 In The Beginning... All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface NSSet(Functional)

- (NSSet *)cp_map:(id(^)(id obj))block;

@end
```

.m File

```
//
//  NSSetFunctional.m
//  CoreParse
//
//  Created by Tom Davie on 06/03/2011.
//  Copyright 2011 In The Beginning... All rights reserved.
//

#import "NSSetFunctional.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@implementation NSSet(Functional)

- (NSSet *)cp_map:(id(^)(id obj))block
{
    NSUInteger c = [self count];
    id *resultingObjects = malloc(c * sizeof(id));

    NSUInteger nonNilCount = 0;
    for (id obj in self)
    {
        id r = block(obj);
        if (nil != r)
        {
            resultingObjects[nonNilCount] = r;
            nonNilCount++;
        }
    }

    NSSet *s = [NSSet setWithObjects:resultingObjects count:nonNilCount];
    free(resultingObjects);
    return s;
}

@end
```

I am at a loss as to how to get this to work. As I said, I am a newbie to IOS programming and this truly has me stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't looked to much at your code but 'unrecognized selector' errors seem to be a problem in how the code is setup or linked. Just combining them might have 'solved' the problem while masking others. Maybe look at how you integrated the 3rd party library again?

Comment: I'm new to IOS coding. I looked it up and one solution said to drag the xcodeproj file into a new folder defined in your app to separate the code from your own. That is what I did. I added this to my question.

Comment: are you using static libraries? or is it all one big app

Comment: You're using a sub project, have you set the target in the sub project as a dependancy of your target in the main project?

Comment: Daij - this (CoreParse) is a subproject of my project.

Comment: Dave, I did set the target as a dependency of my project. That was part of the NUI install instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the category's implementation file (NSSetFunctional.m) is being compiled and linked into your target. There are a couple ways to verify this, but the easy way is to select that file in Xcode, open the Utilities drawer (right 'sidebar'), and select the File inspector (page icon). Under "Target Membership" make sure the box next to your app's target is checked.

If this option is not checked, the implementation for those category methods won't be included in the compiled binary, and you'll get exactly the error you describe.

Comment: I took a look - this is a subproject under mine - creating a target called IOSCoreParse. This target is selected for the m file, so it is being built in.

Comment: Is the code that's throwing the exception in iOSCoreParse, or is it in your own code? If it's in iOSCoreParse, make sure that the (built) binary for iOSCoreParse is being linked in to your app's target.

Comment: It is in the IOSCoreParse code. Not sure if I am building properly. For my app, In the build phases tab I have IOSCoreParse set as a target dependency, then I have the IOSCoreparse.a added to the "Link binary with libraries" section. That is what it said to do in the installation for NUI.

Comment: That sounds right. If iOSCoreParse code is throwing the exception, it still sounds like the category isn't being complied and linked into the iOSCoreParse binary (.a file). In other words, it doesn't sound like a problem with the setup of your apps project in relation to iOSCoreParse, so much as with the built setup for iOSCoreParse itself.

Comment: Based on comments received, I have combined everything into one big project. That seems to have solved some of the issues but now the NUI code is throwing errors. Sigh... Guess I will have to try something else.